# How can I get the stat in linux?

Tags: c, linux, stat, procfs

I'm working in Linux and C, and I am trying to get the specific values from `stat`.
In `/proc` when I do `stat` I get multiple values returned.

Now I'm trying to do this like below:

```
thisFile = fopen("/proc/stat","r");
```

and print the individual User, System and Idle Mode so that when I `printf` they can be printed like below.

```
User Mode: 12189
System Mode: 5190
Idle Mode: 443
```

How would I get the individual values for User, System, and Idle Mode? Is it possible?

Comment: You can use `scanf()` function to parse `/proc/stat` file. The order of fields is documented in `man stat`.

Comment: It is not `man stat`, but `man proc` a.k.a [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

Answer (score 1):

According to [man 5 proc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), the first four fields in the `cpu` line of `/proc/stat` are

> user (1) Time spent in user mode.
>     nice   (2) Time spent in user mode with low priority (nice).
>     system (3) Time spent in system mode.
>     idle (4) Time spent in the idle task.

So one possibility would be to read that file line by line into a buffer using [fgets()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3p.html), and then use [sscanf()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3p.html) to parse the relevant `cpu` line:

```
char buf[2048];

while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), thisfile) != NULL) {
    // search for the line with "cpu "
    if (strncmp(buf, "cpu ", 4) == 0) {
        unsigned long long user;
        unsigned long long nice;
        unsigned long long system;
        unsigned long long idle;
        // extract four space separated integer values from what comes after "cpu "
        if (sscanf(buf, "cpu %llu %llu %llu %llu", &user, &nice, &system, &idle) != 4)
            // if the return value is not 4
            // there is an error, handle it

        // user, nice, system and idle variables now hold the desired values
        // print them or do whatever you like
    }
}
```

This answer implements what was suggested already in comments before.